# Get an error while emptying the recycle bin

Tags: sharepoint-online

I get an error while trying to empty the recycle bin?
This is the error message:

> "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is your recycle bin contains more than 200 items, so please select less that 200 items and delete it.

I think SharePoint will not allow to delete more that 200 items at a time.

Comment: Hi my recycle bin contains indeed more than 200 items. But even selecting one item of the 200 i get an error message.

Comment: https://sohamblogs.wordpress.com/tag/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-in-sharepoint/                                                                                                               http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-empty-recycle-bin.html     - Can you please try both method

Comment: Tried the first part but did not help. Second part i don't have admin -rigts so i have contacted my sharepoint-administrator

Comment: The Sharepoint-administrator emptied the recycle bin. Thanks for the help. Greetings, Peter Kiers

Comment: Hello @PeterKiers thanks for your feedback and accepting the correct answer, I would like to inform you that you have now upvote permission, so please don't forget to also upvote the helpful answer that prvoided to your question